# SQL Server 2012 does not use specifically created non-clustered index in an update statement and causes deadlocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, deadlock, database-administration

My Java program executes following parameterized statements (table name and column name changed) concurrently.

```
insert into t_test (a,b,c) values (@param1, @param2, @param3)
update t_test set a=@param1 where id=@param2
update t_test set a=@param1 where a=@param2 and b=@param3 and c=@param4
```

The table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE t_test (
    [id]            [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [a]             [int] NULL,
    [b]             [int] NULL,
    [c]             [int] NULL
);
```

And an index is created specifically for this query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [i_test] ON [t_test] (a,b,c);
```

I found from the query plans that when the size of the table was below ~3000 rows, the database selected the rows to be updated by clustered index scan; while after the size of the table growed to be larger than ~3000 rows, the database started to use i_test.

The problem is, if the database uses clustered index scan, it will try to acquire an U lock on every row of t_test, which causes deadlocks when executed concurrently.

Actual queries are something like:

Transaction A:

```
insert into t_test (a,b,c) values (1, 1, 0)
-- say the id inserted is 1
update t_test set a=1 where id=1
update t_test set a=1 where a=1 and b=2 and c=0 --Deadlock
```

Transaction B:

```
insert into t_test (a,b,c) values (1, 2, 0)
-- say the id inserted is 2
update t_test set a=1 where id=2
update t_test set a=1 where a=1 and b=2 and c=0  --Deadlock
```

This phenomenon is reproducible by executing direct sqls in SSMS.

Please tell me if there is a good solution to force the database to use i_test without adding query hints to the update statement, thanks.

Comment: Show us the actual code you are using to update it.

Comment: Make sure statistics are up-to-date. How many rows are updated? If it is always one (or zero), the index should be declared unique.

Comment: @zhenchuan9r . . . When using the index, it should be using a seek, not a scan.  No lock should be placed on very row.  The scan on the smaller table is because the table fits on a very small number of data pages (probably just 1), so locking a page and the table is the same thing.

Comment: SQL Server will not deadlock this update statement. Your other sessions will be blocked, but not deadlocked. If you have a deadlock, you are not showing us all the code. Lock escalation might occur if there are multiple rows matching your criteria.

Comment: I supplemented another two statements which is included in the transaction. I am sorry but I cannot show actual codes.

Comment: The final update statement actually updates 0 rows but during the execution the database tries to acquire an U lock  (but will not hold it) on a row inserted by another concurrent transaction, which causes the deadlock.

Comment: The example sqls given are enough for reproducing the deadlock.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  It was using clustered index scan which was clearly described in the query plan.